# Crash in Swift 2.0 with Dropbox SDK

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I've written a Swift 2.0 version of the PhotoRoulette example app for iOS using the Dropbox v1.3.13 SDK. Linking my account and creating a session work just fine, but when I call `restClient.loadMetaData(path: String!,  withHash:String!)`, I get a crash that usually shows me only the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1) banner in red, or occasionally a stack trace that looks like this:

```
2015-10-18 08:41:06.692 DropboxSwift[19515:2683506] -[__NSCFString networkRequestStarted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe31161a630 2015-10-18 08:41:06.707 DropboxSwift[19515:2683506] ***
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString networkRequestStarted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe31161a630'

*** First throw call stack: (

 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f397f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111546deb objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f3a058d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2edf7a ___forwarding___ + 970
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2edb28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   DropboxSwift                        0x000000010f15ddb6 -[DBRequest initWithURLRequest:andInformTarget:selector:] + 215
 6   DropboxSwift                        0x000000010f15fd8a -[DBRestClient loadMetadata:withParams:] + 149
 7   DropboxSwift                        0x000000010f155135 _TFC12DropboxSwift19PhotoViewController20didPressRandomButtonfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 1253
 8   DropboxSwift                        0x000000010f154a7b _TFC12DropboxSwift19PhotoViewController14viewWillAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 571

 (Truncated)
```

Since this appears to be generated from a call within the SDK, I'm hoping somebody can help me make sense of it. I don't know if it's due to something I'm doing wrong in my Swift code (still very new to Swift), or it's an incompatibility between the SDK and Swift 2.0.

Comment: The problem is your call to `initWithURLRequest:andInformTarget:selector:`. Your `target:` is invalid. My guess is that you've assigned a bad `delegate` here.

Comment: Nice tutorial here: http://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/

Comment: The selector in DBRestClient.loadMetadata is requestDidLoadMetadata: which is also defined in DBRestClient. You didn't happen to alter the SDK did you? I'm not sure off hand if the Core SDK (written in Obj-C) you're using has been tested with Swift 2.0 though.

Comment: matt: My code does not explicitly call `initWithURLRequest:andInformTarget:selector:`  I am guessing that the SDK is calling that from my `restClient.loadMetaData(path: String!,  withHash:String!)` call.

Comment: Greg: I have not done anything that would override anything in the SDK. I merely used the Swift "interpretation" of `[self.restClient loadMetadata:photosRoot withHash:photosHash]` as used in the PhotoRoulette example project.